# How can I access queue messages in Azure using Python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-queues, azure-storage-queues

I have some data in the queues which I want to access in my python code.

I am using the following code:

```
from azure.storage.queue import QueueService

queue_service = QueueService(account_name='', account_key='')

messages = queue_service.get_messages('queue', num_messages=5)

for message in messages:
    print(message.id)
    print(message.content)
```

But the output of the content is in the form of some coded message.

How do I decode it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `print(base64.b64decode(message.content))`.

```
from azure.storage.queue import QueueService
import base64

queue_service = QueueService(account_name='', account_key='')

messages = queue_service.get_messages('queue', num_messages=5)

for message in messages:
    print(message.id)
    print(message.content)
    print(base64.b64decode(message.content))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
from azure.storage.queue import QueueService, QueueMessageFormat
queue_service = QueueService(account_name=account_name, account_key=account_key)
#queue_service.encode_function = QueueMessageFormat.binary_base64decode
queue_service.decode_function = QueueMessageFormat.binary_base64decode
messages = queue_service.get_messages(...
```